# Can we write an event / function on "Publish" or "Publish All Customizations" button in MS CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016

Actually i want to execute a functionality every time a developer publishes customizations. Hence, can we write any custom logic on click of "Publish entity" or "Publish All Customizations" buttons. OOB or un supported way either?

Its not a business requirement, its more of a streamlining code development process in the team.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what exactly are you trying to achieve? I cannot guess what the use case for this would be.

Comment: Blame tracking :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39265795/crm-plugin-for-publish-and-publish-all-messages/39291051#39291051) is an example which explains how to create a plugin for the Publish/PublishAll events. I created it for a very similar question so I'm sure that you will find it helpful.

You can download the plugin project and CRM solution that I used for that example from my [GitHub](https://github.com/fedejousset/PublishAudit).

Answer (score 6):

You could write a plugin that listens for the [`Publish` and `PublishAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328576.aspx) messages and runs the functionality you want.