# Dynamics 365 - Monitor instance for Customization changes

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

We have a business requirement (more financial compliance requirement) to monitor our production instance for any updates/releases/changes. This is to meet audit obligations so that we can prove that all changes were performed only inside of established release processes ie. no one is making changes to the CRM instance outside of this.

To be clear we already have an established release management process, but the question is being asked if there was a way to monitor the CRM instance to prove that indeed no changes are being made outside of release management. We have a Dynamics 365 online instance. I've searched for something suitable but am not able to find anything so the question here is posed to get pointers / ideas on potential solutions to this problem or even pointers to where I could begin my research into potential solutions.

As a background, the CRM application has financial data and hence we have 'over the top' financial controls/legal obligations to meet and hence the requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explore this [Change Tracking Solution](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crminthefield/2017/10/23/new-from-microsoft-labs-change-tracking-solution-for-dynamics-365-released/) from MS Labs, basically to track all the Publish/Publish All from CRM org.

> The Change Tracking solution helps in tracking down the details of changes on who updated an entity, JavaScript, assemblies and processes along with the time of update. This solution is built on Dynamics 365 and as well works on Dynamics CRM 2016 (Online/ On premises)

I never tried this, but this was from a team which I worked earlier in MS internally.

If this not fits you, you can implement a custom plugin on `Publish` and `PublishAll` messages yourself. [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39265795/7920473)